# Windows (7) "Server" Service is not starting

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I've noticed that my Server service is not starting, though it is marked as "Automatic".

I've checked the event viewer for the errors and found out, that it is not starting due to the error: Invalid access to memory location.

What is wrong here? And how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a host of reasons and cures for this, too many to guess by what you've provided.

Having said that, it sounds like there may be a corrupt file.

Basic outline of things to do/try:

- Run a disk check (like `chkdsk`) to look for disk or file-system corruption (`/f` to fix it).
- Run the system file checker (`sfc /scannow`) to see if it finds corrupt/missing system files.
- Use the System Restore to go back to a point where it works.